# creating a view SQL, always getting error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE VIEW CARAVAN AS
    SELECT ANNUAL_RENT, BOOKING_FEE
    FROM CARAVAN
    WHERE ANNUAL_RENT < 3000
```

this is my failed sql. the error is

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: Your `create view` obviously has a `select`.  Hence, I conclude that this is not the code you are running (perhaps you are only running the first line).

Comment: i am 100% that i am running the entire code, but the error always comes up

Comment: You'd also be getting either an ORA-00955 or ORA-01731 with that code, depending on whether you already have a table called `CARAVAN` as the `FROM` clause expects. Do you have a strange invisible character before or after the `SELECT` perhaps? Try copying and pasting what is shown here and running that; or retyping it.

Comment: Am not sure my deadline is around the corner and still have a lot of complete!

Comment: how can your `view` and the `table` have the same name? you should be getting a different error instead, as @AlexPoole points out

Comment: By looking at the SQL what do you think i should do? I'm trying to get booking_fee and annual_rent so that it works out a certain about of money from the rent and all selected from caravan

Comment: You should give the view a different name to the table (if you actually need a view); and retype the whole statement to get rid of anything invisible that is making it think the select keyword is missing. If you still get the error after retyping it cleanly, what client or tool are you running this in?

Comment: its running in oracle, i simple clicked onto SQL workshop and view was on the right hand side, this then allows me to create the view, but after creating it the error comes up.

Comment: Besides giving the view a different name due to object naming collisions, once you have the error if the object is created but with a compile error then you will continue to get an error until you CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW instead of just CREATE.

Comment: Is that APEX? Is it possible the view has been created with 'force' at some point and you're just seeing repeated compilation errors of that code somewhere? Try it with `create or replace` too to rule that out.

Comment: Yes it is apex, the problem isn't going away i have a table with all the details but still the error comes up I've tried changing it about, yet the error comes up

Answer (score 3):

Try running just the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT ANNUAL_RENT, BOOKING_FEE
FROM CARAVAN
WHERE ANNUAL_RENT < 3000
```

And see if that returns a result, or if it generates an error.

My suspicion is that `CARAVAN` is a view that is `INVALID`. You can check that with a query from a dictionary view, e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_objects
 WHERE object_name = 'CARAVAN'
```

If you don't have privileges on `dba_objects`, then reference the `all_objects`  instead.

The referenced `CARAVAN` object is either an object in your schema, a public synonym, or its an invalid reference.

As Alex Poole mentioned, it's possible to create a view that has invalid syntax, by using a `CREATE FORCE VIEW` statement. (I suspect that the referenced object `CARAVAN` is a view that contains invalid syntax.)

---

Identifiers in Oracle have to be *unique* within a schema. It's very strange that you would be creating a view named `CARAVAN` that references an object already named `CARAVAN`. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve with this particular `CREATE VIEW` statement.

Comment: It still doesn't allow me to create a view, i can view the table, so i know they isn't a problem with the table

Comment: @AHMER93: have you tried running the statement from a sqlplus command line?  if `CARAVAN` is a table in the current schema, then do not run create a view named `CARAVAN` in the same schema, give the view a *different* name.  (I don't understand why you would need to create a view in the first place, what problem does that solve?)

Comment: It's okay now I've solved the problem thank you everyone for your help much appreciated

Comment: Does anyone know about triggers and how to insert/delete and drop?